# Azure DF Parameterizing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to parameterize a mapping data flow in Azure DF UI. I am declaring a variable in the pipeline, which is taking the result from a lookup value - the current timestamp of a table. In the mapping dataflow though I am defining a parameter, which I would like to take the value of the variable declared in the pipeline. The variable is of type string, holding the current timestamp value.

[this is the pipeline in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2o9a.jpg)

[the dataflow parameter is taking the value of the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt3ve.jpg)

[I am setting empty string as a default value - I tried also setting it to take variable value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpS1v.jpg)

[that is a filter expression to filter based on this timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtOzR.jpg)

So I guess I have to add a default value to the parameter value inside the Data Flow. How should this be done using the expression language? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

***When you are passing the Data flow parameter value from the Pipeline, the default value is not at all required.*** You can leave it as it is without giving any value.

[image]

When you debug the pipeline, the value is taken from the pipeline only and not from the default value.

**For the Data preview of each transformation**, you can provide a temporary hardcoded value by going through the **click to see parameters** below. It will help us to check whether the Data flow preview is giving correct results or not.

[image]

**Please go through my repro for your reference:**

This is my sample data

[image]

After creating the `myparam` parameter in the Data flow, I have passed my variable `myname` to it from pipeline. Here, I have given the value of the `myname` variable as `@string('Rakesh')` to filter this name.

[image]

Don't check that checkbox.

The condition in the Filter as `Name==$myparam`.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add a default value you can add a previous timestamp JUST LIKE THIS  to hold and btw it will not be used as its an dynamic paramter so dont worry just place it there, but it will allow the debug to preview data and example is and it run in my case as i am also getting the same lookup max date and using in an dynamic Query
[image: EXAMPLE OF Default Value how to add Expression]